# tikz pgf - Add background color to specific cells of a Matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices, backgrounds

Hi i'm interested in how to add background to specific cells of a matrix.

I already know a bit about how to build a matrix, my given code looks like:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, fit, matrix, positioning, shapes}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
    \node (B) {$B^\prime=$};
    \matrix (M) [matrix of math nodes,left delimiter={[}, right delimiter={]},
    matrix anchor=west, right=0.5em of B, 
    column 1/.style={anchor=base east},
    column 2/.style={anchor=base east},
    column 3/.style={anchor=base east}]
    {
      a & b & c\\
      b & d & e\\
      c & e & a+b+1\\
    };
    \node  [fit=(M-1-1) (M-1-3), draw, rectangle, blue]{};    
    \node  [fit=(M-2-2) (M-2-3), draw, rectangle, blue]{};
    \node  [fit=(M-3-3) (M-3-3), draw, rectangle, blue]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

As you can see im creating a right-aligned matrix, because my element at cell(3,3) is very long. To point out that my matrix is quadratic, I thought about highlighting row elements 1-1 to 1-3, 2-2 to 2-3, and element 3-3.

I would want to give them a background color, lets say some sort of blue. I didn't manage to fill out the rectangles without covering the matrix elements below.

I would be greatful for any hints or solutions :)

Comment: Does this answer help? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112433/87678

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You can simply add fills. For instance, if the 1-1 cell should be shaded, replace the first line by of the matrix `|[fill=blue!30]|a & b & c\\ `. If you want to fill the rectangles you draw with fit, you may want to load the `backgrounds` library and do the fills/fits in a scope `\begin{scope}[on background layer]` such that the texts stay in the foreground. You can of course fill a whole column by `column 1/.style={anchor=base east,fill=red},`, say, and likewise for rows.

Comment: @David Purton Thanks, the |[fill=<color>| option is something i want, but:
"Fill" does follow the written letters, not the cells of a matrix. So if I do this operation cell-wise, the filled boxes will overlap, and have some white areas in between. 

I want boxes with equal height for element 1,1 to 1,3, 2,2 to 2,3 and element 3,3

is that possible?

Comment: You only need to add `nodes={minimum height=6mm},` to the options of the matrix. Of course, `6mm` is not carved in stone.

Comment: @marmot I think your comment about adding an background layer is more intuitive. Is there a way to draw 3 boxes like this example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220646/tikz-matrix-background-color-for-unevenly-sized-cells?rq=1

for my written cells? I tried    
    \scoped[on background layer]
     \node[fill=pink!50,
          fit=(M-1-1)(M-1-3) (M-2-2)(M-2-3) (M-3-3)]   {};

Comment: I am sorry, I do not understand your question. Can't you just try it out? (Yes, I think it should be possible. Notice that I prefer to use `\begin{scope}[on background layer] <stuff> \end{scope}` because I never really understood what `\scoped` precisely does.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i finally managed to find my desired answer.

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, fit, matrix, positioning, shapes, backgrounds,
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
    \node (B) {$B^\prime=$};
    \matrix (M) [matrix of math nodes,left delimiter={[}, right delimiter={]},
    matrix anchor=west, right=0.5em of B, 
    column 1/.style={anchor=base east},
    column 2/.style={anchor=base east},
    column 3/.style={anchor=base east}]
    {
      a & b & c\\
      b & d & e\\
      c & e & a+b+1\\
    };
    \scoped[on background layer]
    {
    \node[fill=pink!50, fit=(M-1-1)(M-1-3) ]   {};
    \node[fill=pink!50, fit=(M-2-2)(M-2-3) ]   {};
    \node[fill=pink!50, fit=(M-3-3)(M-3-3) ]   {};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

it's not super perfect, but i'll take it. Thanks for your suggestions.

[image]